# Detaching volumes (for a fresh restart) when shutting down Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have a Docker Compose (file is named `my-main-db.yml`) that creates a MySQL 8.0 container:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  my-main-db:
    env_file:
      - .env
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: my-main-db
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MY_SERVICE_DB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: my_service_db_local
      MYSQL_USER: $MY_SERVICE_DB_APP_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $MY_SERVICE_DB_APP_PASSWORD
    volumes:
      - ./my-service-db-data:/var/lib/mysql
```

To fire this up I run:

```
docker-compose -f my-main-db.yml up
```

And it runs just fine, I can connect to it and also see it running via `docker ps`.

If I want to stop this container and **keep** all the data inside of it, I shut it down with:

```
docker-compose -f my-main-db.yml down
```

But if I want to stop this container and **erase** all the data inside of it, so that it starts up brand new (and clean), my understanding is that I need to detach or delete the volume. So I have been trying to shut it down like so:

```
docker-compose -f my-main-db.yml down -v
```

However, when I do this, and then start it back up, my data is still all there, whereas I was hoping for a brand new (empty) database.

**Can anyone spot where I'm going awry?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docker-compose down -v` will delete *named volumes*, but it won't delete directories you've mounted as bind mounts (as in your configuration). For that you would need to use `rm -rf` yourself.

If you want `docker-compose` to manage the volumes, used a named volume instead:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  my-main-db:
    env_file:
      - .env
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: my-main-db
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MY_SERVICE_DB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: my_service_db_local
      MYSQL_USER: $MY_SERVICE_DB_APP_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $MY_SERVICE_DB_APP_PASSWORD
    volumes:
      - my-service-db-data:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  my-service-db-data:
```

This will allocate a docker volume for you automatically when starting up the stack, and will remove it when you run `docker-compose down -v`.

---

For example, if I have the following in `.env`:

```
MY_SERVICE_DB_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
MY_SERVICE_DB_APP_USER=myservice
MY_SERVICE_DB_APP_PASSWORD=secret
```

I can bring up the stack:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

And then connect to mysql and create a table:

```
$ mysql -h docker -u myservice -psecret my_service_db_local
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 10
Server version: 8.0.23 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MySQL [my_service_db_local]> create table testtable (id int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.065 sec)

MySQL [my_service_db_local]> show tables;
+-------------------------------+
| Tables_in_my_service_db_local |
+-------------------------------+
| testtable                     |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.004 sec)

MySQL [my_service_db_local]> ^DBye
```

Now if I bring down the stack with `-v`:

```
$ docker-compose down -v
Stopping my-main-db ... done
WARNING: Found orphan containers (docker_test_1) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --remove-orphans flag to clean it up.
Removing my-main-db ... done
Removing network docker_default
Removing volume docker_my-service-db-data
```

...you can see that Docker has removed the `docker_my-service-db-data`
volume.  If we restart the stack:

```
$ docker-compose up -d
Creating network "docker_default" with the default driver
Creating volume "docker_my-service-db-data" with default driver
WARNING: Found orphan containers (docker_test_1) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --remove-orphans flag to clean it up.
Creating my-main-db ... done
```

We can connect to mysql and see that the table no longer exists,
because the database has been re-created from scratch:

```
$ mysql -h docker -u myservice -psecret my_service_db_local
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 8
Server version: 8.0.23 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MySQL [my_service_db_local]> show tables;
Empty set (0.004 sec)

MySQL [my_service_db_local]>
```

Comment: Thanks @larsks (+1) but this doesn't seem to work. I made sure nothing was running (via `docker ps`), manually deleted my data folder (`my-service-db-data/`), applied your change, ran docker-compose up (same command posted in my question), added some data to it, shut it down (without the `-v` option), started it back up, confirmed the data was still there, shut it down (this time with the `-v` option), and started it back up again. Data is still there. Am I missing something?

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup I've added a complete example to the question. If you're seeing different behavior, ensure you're using exactly the `Dockerfile` from this answer and that you're seeing the same messages from Docker (in particular, the `Removing volume docker_my-service-db-data`) when bringing down the stack with `-v`.

Comment: Interesting, when I **don't** specify `-d` on the `docker-compose up` command, then none of this works (data directory is never deleted when I `docker-compose down` with `-v`). But if I add the `-d` to the `up` command, everything works. Thanks!